# Saving verbose_name=

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

After changing the `verbose_name` argument for some fields I am still seeing the old text. I was recommended to use migrations, but since I am using Django 1.5 it is not an option. Any other solutions?

Comment: You don't have to migrate after changing `verbose_name`. Simply restarting the development server should do.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. There's no need to do anything else when you change verbose_name in Django 1.5.

Comment: @Romua1d I took the liberty to rephrase your question to keep it from downvoted and closed. I hope that was what you meant.

Comment: @Selcuk I can't help feeling you've been a bit aggressive in your edit here. How do you know OP was still seeing the old text?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I guessed that OP meant it by writing "After save file - old result" but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank u, for editing.

Comment: I am using Django 1.5 it is not an option migrate changes

Comment: @Romua1d You don't need to use migrations. Only restart the server.

Comment: @Selcuk changes dont save after restart server. maybe need more find solutions

Comment: Where do you see the old text?

Comment: @Selcuk i am have verbose_name=_u("Model"), change to Model1 and restart server, and no result

Comment: [Caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) perhaps?..

Comment: Me need more info about this! Thank you